# How to fix the error “Could not find Angular Material core theme” in Angular 2?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I am practically new in Angular2 and inherited the project with Angular 2 frontend.  After switching to the new Angular 4.0 on console I see the error:

"compatibility.ts:221 Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming"

The mdb.min.css is in the app/assets/css folder.  The specification in package.json shows the following:

```
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
...
"angular-bootstrap-md": "*"
```

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to import a theme into your global css or sass file:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

or alternatively include it in your `index.html` file:

```
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

As in the [theming documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) already mentioned Angular Material provides the following pre-built themes:

- deeppurple-amber.css
- indigo-pink.css
- pink-bluegrey.css
- purple-green.css

You have to include one of these themes or you create your own custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when i upgraded from Angular version 7 to 8.Even after imported to .sass file / index.html / angular.json file.I tried upgrading angular material separately again , it solved the issue.

> ng update @angular/material@latest

Answer (score 0):

Please insert below code into your styles.css or styles.scss which is located in your src folder.

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

You can select any css under the prebuilt-themes folder.